# Execute command from another directory without really moving

Tags: shell, bundler

Consider this directory structure
`/dir1/Quack.sh`
`/dir2/` <- We are here

Is it possible to execute `Quack.sh` as if I were currently in `/dir1/` without actually `cd`'ing there?

The main reason I'm asking is because **Bundle** is complaining when running executables who depends on it when the executable is ran from outside the folder. The executable runs fine if executed from the directory it is contained in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create sub-shell and do cd, script execution:

```
(cd ../dir1/; ./Quack.sh)
```

OR else use `find -execdir`

```
find ../dir2/ -maxdepth1 -name "Quack.sh" -execdir '{}' \;
```

Comment: Another option would be to put something along the lines of `cd $(dirname "${0}")` at the top of `Quack.sh` - then you could just run `../dir1/Quack.sh`, and it would take care of the `cd` for you...